# Properly align country names and values for horizontal bar graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to align the country names for the graph below as follows:

```
country1                        50% bargraph
country loooooooong name       100% bargraph
country2                        50% bargraph
country middle name             50% bargraph
country3                         5% bargraph
```

I have been trying for hours now but still no success. I tried to fix it with the "scale_x_discrete" function:

```
cat(df$info_country, "\t", df$indicator, "%")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
remove(list = ls())

### data frame for bar graph
df <- data.frame(
  info_country = c("country1", "country loooooooong name", "country2", "country middle name", "country3"),
  indicator = c(50,100,50,50,5))

### change factor level for ggplot order
df$info_country <- factor(df$info_country, levels = df$info_country[order(df$indicator)])
factor(df$info_country)

### change order for naming
df <- df %>%
  arrange(indicator)

bar_graph <- df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = info_country, y = indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, fill = "#EE5859") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(df$info_country, " ", df$indicator, "%", sep=" ")) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color="white"), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(color="white"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0),
  )

bar_graph
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to also align the bars with a fixed distance so that the length of my country names does not matter and the bar always starts at the same distance. I tried to just add empty spaces to the country name so that characters have the same lenght. But somehow for ggplot spaces seem to be shorter than actual letters (see below difference between two different datasets). Any ideas to fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  info_country = c("country1", "country loooooong", "country2", "country midd", "country3"),
  indicator = c(50,100,50,50,5))

## second dataframe with short names
# df <- data.frame(
#   info_country = c("c", "a", "b", "d", "e"),
#   indicator = c(50,100,50,50,5))
# 




### change factor level for ggplot order
df$info_country <- factor(df$info_country, levels = df$info_country[order(df$indicator)])
factor(df$info_country)
df$info_country


## add spaces
df$info_country <-str_pad(df$info_country, width=18, pad = " ", side = "right")
df$info_country

### change order for naming
df <- df %>%
  arrange(indicator)

bar_graph <- df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = info_country, y = indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, fill = "#EE5859") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -2, label = paste(indicator, "%", sep=" ")), 
            hjust = 1, size = 11 * 0.8 / ggplot2::.pt, color = "grey30") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, limits = c(-5, 100)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color="white"), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(color="white"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0),
  )

bar_graph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve this is via a `geom_text` layer to add the right aligned values to the plot. For the `size` and the `color` I've used the `theme_grey` defaults for `axis.text`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  info_country = c("country1", "country loooooooong name", "country2", "country middle name", "country3"),
  indicator = c(50,100,50,50,5))

### change factor level for ggplot order
df$info_country <- factor(df$info_country, levels = df$info_country[order(df$indicator)])
factor(df$info_country)
#> [1] country1                 country loooooooong name country2                
#> [4] country middle name      country3                
#> 5 Levels: country3 country1 country2 ... country loooooooong name

### change order for naming
df <- df %>%
  arrange(indicator)

bar_graph <- df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = info_country, y = indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, fill = "#EE5859") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -2, label = paste(indicator, "%", sep=" ")), 
            hjust = 1, size = 11 * 0.8 / ggplot2::.pt, color = "grey30") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, limits = c(-5, 100)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color="white"), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(color="white"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0),
  )

bar_graph
```

[image]

**EDIT** To increase the distance between the labels and the percentages you could increase the margin of the labels via e.g. `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0, margin = margin(r = 6, unit = "cm"))`. However in that case you should add option `clip=off` to `coord_flip()` to prevent that labels are clipped off when hitting the boundaries and also set the color of the ticks to `NA` which means no color at all:

```r
bar_graph <- df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = info_country, y = indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, fill = "#EE5859") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -2, label = paste(indicator, "%", sep=" ")), 
            hjust = 1, size = 11 * 0.8 / ggplot2::.pt, color = "grey30") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, limits = c(-2, 100)) +
  # Use clip = "off" to prevent that percentage labels are clipped off
  coord_flip(clip = "off") + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
    # Set color of ticks to NA
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color=NA), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(color=NA),
    # Increase the margin 
    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0, margin = margin(r = 6, unit = "cm")),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0),
  )

bar_graph
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot man! one thing I do not understand, why do you use: size = 11 * 0.8 / ggplot2::.pt. why not just sth like 12?

Comment: Yep. Of course you could simply use 12 or .. The reason was to make sure that we have the same font size as for the axis label. First. You have to keep in mind that `size` in ggplot2 is measured in "mm". Therefore if one wants so set the size in "pt" one has to use " / ggplot2::.pt" to convert from "pt" to "mm". Second. The "11"  is the base_size of theme_grey measured in "pt" , while third the fontsize of axis.text is defined as .8 * base_size. So all together 11 * .8 / .pt gives us the size of axis.text in "mm".

Comment: one more thing: geom_text(aes(y = -2, label = paste(indicator, "%", sep=" ")), the "-2" basically defines the distance between the country name and the percentages. so the allignment depends on the length of the country name. I have just realized that I need the bars and percentages to always start after like 6cm. is it possible to set absolute values?

Comment: I have found a way to fix this. I just add spaces to the county names: df$info_county <-str_pad(df$info_county, width=17, pad = " ", side = "right"). but somehow for ggplot the lenght is not the same if its a letter or a space.

Comment: Hi titeuf. First. The width of letters and spaces depends on the chosen font and is nothing about ggplot2. Only in case of a monospaced font will all letters (including spaces) have the same width (see the answer by StupidWolf). Second. See my edit for a possible solution to your issue.

Comment: Yeah, amazing, I think I slowly manage to understand how ggplot works. ;) almost what I want, now the r=6cm is from the end of my country name, but I need the margin from the beginnin of the country name. but it actually works now with family = "mono". thank you :)

Comment: haha, just realized that monospace is not really an option. looks terrible :)))

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the columns first then join, this should work for most label sizes, first you work out the width for the 1st and 2nd part:

```
w1 = max(nchar(as.character(df$info_country)))
w2 = max(nchar(as.character(df$indicator)))
```

And we pad them accordingly, you can see the result:

```
l1 = with(df,str_pad(info_country,w1,side="right"))
l2 = with(df,str_pad(indicator,w2,side="left"))

df$lab = paste0(l1," ",l2,"% bargraph")

df
              info_country indicator                                    lab
1                 country3         5 country3                   5% bargraph
2                 country1        50 country1                  50% bargraph
3                 country2        50 country2                  50% bargraph
4      country middle name        50 country middle name       50% bargraph
5 country loooooooong name       100 country loooooooong name 100% bargraph
```

Unfortunately, to ensure the characters and " " have equal space, we might need to force the label text to monospace:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=info_country,y=indicator)) + 
geom_col() + scale_x_discrete(labels=df$lab) + coord_flip() + 
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0,family = "mono"))
```

[image]

Maybe there's a better way to use the fonts but I am honestly not good with it