# Horizontal bar graph with ggplot: Fixed distance of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is related to the one I have already asked here: [Properly align country names and values for horizontal bar graph in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647927/properly-align-country-names-and-values-for-horizontal-bar-graph-in-ggplot/64648681?noredirect=1#comment114531542_64648681)

I would like to produce the following bar graph, but want to make sure that the distance from the beginning of the country name to the bar graph is always the same. So no matter if I read in the first or second df, it should always be the same distance as here:

```
#df1
loooooong country1   100% Bar
looooong country2     99% Bar

#df2
short country1       100% Bar
short country2        99% Bar
```

As it is for now, the distance between the end of the country name and the bar is always the same. I have found a workaround with filling up country names with spaces and use monospace font, but this looks pretty bad.. :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


### first df
df <- data.frame(
  info_country = c("country1", "country loooooooong name", "country2", "country middle name", "country3"),
  indicator = c(50,100,50,50,5))

### second df
# df <- data.frame(
#   info_country = c("country1", "country3", "country2", "country4", "country5"),
#   indicator = c(50,100,50,50,5))

### change factor level for ggplot order
df$info_country <- factor(df$info_country, levels = df$info_country[order(df$indicator)])
factor(df$info_country)


### create bar graph
bar_graph <- df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = info_country, y = indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, fill = "#EE5859") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -2, label = paste(indicator, "%", sep=" ")), 
            hjust = 1, size = 11 * 0.8 / ggplot2::.pt, color = "grey30") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, limits = c(-2, 100)) +
  # Use clip = "off" to prevent that percentage labels are clipped off
  coord_flip(clip = "off") + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
    # Set color of ticks to NA
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color=NA), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(color=NA),
    # Increase the margin 
    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0, margin = margin(r = 6, unit = "cm")),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0),
  )

bar_graph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply repeat the trick of plotting text as if it were axis labels. You can control the distance between the left edge of the labels and the start of the bars by setting the labels' `hjust` to 0 and using a large negative number for `y` in their aesthetic. A value of -100 is nicely symmetrical:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = info_country, y = indicator)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, fill = "#EE5859") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -2, label = paste(indicator, "%", sep=" ")), 
            hjust = 1, size = 11 * 0.8 / .pt, color = "grey30") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -100, label = info_country), 
            hjust = 0, size = 11 * 0.8 / .pt, color = "grey30") +
  labs(x = "", y = "") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, limits = c(-100, 100)) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = NA), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = NA),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]